# Getting initialized objects without using static

Tags: java

I want receive an initialized object from an other class without creating this object new or use static. Is that possible ?

I try to make an example on the fly dont know if it works:

```
package.display    
public class Display extends JFrame{    
    public Display(){
        initUI();
    }
    public void initUI(){
        // initialize panel1
        Panel1 panel1 = new Panel1();
        // setting window adding panel1
        this.setSize(400,400);
        this.add(panel1);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
   public static void main(String[] args){
        new Display();
   }
}
package.panle1
public class Panel1 extends JPanel{ 
    Canvas canvas;   
    public Display(){
        initUI();
    }
    public void initUI(){
        // initialize canvas and panel2 
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200);
        Panel2 panel2 = new Panel2();
        // adding canvas and panel2
        this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.North);
        this.add(panle2, BorderLayout.South);
    }
    public Canvas getCanvas(){
        return canvas;
    }
}
package.panle2
public class Panel2 extends JPanel{    
    public Display(){
        initUI();
    }
    public void initUI(){
        // just 1 button
        JButton btn1 = new JButton();
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            // create new JPanel and center on canvas
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                JPanel canvasPanel = new JPanel();
                canvasPanel.setSize(100,100);
                canvasPanel.setLocationRelativeTo(
                // and here is my PROBLEM
                // how i get this panel1 canvas object without creating new ?
                // getter getCanvas() dont work with existing object instance
                // i want exactly the object which is created when its called
                // from display and not the way i have to make new Panel1
        });
        this.add(btn1);
    }
}
```

( my Problem is described in the code last part )

The only solution i know is static and that works fine. The word
static is really nice i would use it all over the place because its so convenient
to get access to all.
With reflection i dont know. I saw only an exampel where you have to create also a new instance of the object and that i dotn want.

Soon i want go perhaps 3d programming and starting with OpenGL. There i read you have to take the objects all time with you and cant use the word static like in lwgl.

Thats why i ask this question to see which possibilities i have to solve problems like that. I hope anyone can help and thx.

Comment: Pass it to the ```Panel2``` constructor; ```Panel2 panel2 = new Panel2(this);```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is creating a `final` instance of *Panel1* ,so you'll be able to access the `getCanvas()` method of that object everywhere in your class even inside of the *inner class*:

```
public class Panel2 extends JPanel{    
    final Panel1 panel1=new Panel1();
    public Display(){
        initUI();
    }
    public void initUI(){
        // just 1 button
        JButton btn1 = new JButton();
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            // create new JPanel and center on canvas
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                JPanel canvasPanel = new JPanel();
                canvasPanel.setSize(100,100);
                canvasPanel.setLocationRelativeTo(
                // and here you have access to the canvas of panel1
        });
        this.add(btn1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i think final is not working also for my problem.

Comment: Sorry but i think final is not working also for my problem. Ofc. i get access to getCanvas() but i would get access also with creating a normal object. But that is exactly the problem. Because i want get access to the already created object from -> Display(new Panel1) -> Panel1(new Canvas and Panel2) -> and then from Panel2 getting access to Canvas which was creaded by Panel1 without using a the keyword "new" again because i make a new object.